# Configuring a firewalld killswitch

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, firewalld

I want to configure a firewalld killswitch on my computer but don't know how to go about it.
I want to block all incoming traffic. The outgoing traffic should only be allowed on a specific IP address, port and interface.

Here is a ufw alternative:

```
ufw default deny incoming
ufw default deny outgoing
ufw allow out to $IP port $PORT proto { udp | tcp }
ufw allow out on $VPN_INTERFACE
ufw allow in on $VPN_INTERFACE from any to any port 60002
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was copied from my [own blog](https://meow464.neocities.org/blog/firewalld-vpn-killswitch/) where I explain a bit more about zones, policies and rich rules.

Firewalld works with zones and policies. To accomplish what you want we have to assign all internet facing cards to a VPN-Only zone and create a policy that filters all traffic going into it.

Here I’m going to assume you only want to filter traffic coming from your own machine, therefore the policy will have the ingress zone HOST and the egress zone VPN-Only.

Create the VPN-Only zone:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone VPN-Only
```

Create the VPN-Killswtich policy:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-policy VPN-Killswitch
```

Default target for the policy (this means DROP everything we don’t explicitly allow):

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy VPN-Killswitch --set-target DROP
```

Reload to apply the changes:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Now let’s add the policy rules that allow outbound traffic to the VPN IPs. Repeat this rule for every region replacing 1.2.3.4 with your VPN’s IP. Change openvpn to wireguard if that’s what you are using.

```
firewall-cmd --policy VPN-Killswitch --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" destination address="1.2.3.4" service name="openvpn" accept'
```

Allow outgoing traffic to the local network:

```
firewall-cmd --policy VPN-Killswitch --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" destination address="192.168.1.0/24" accept'
```

Set the ingress zone:

```
firewall-cmd --policy VPN-Killswitch --add-ingress-zone HOST
```

And the egress zone:

```
firewall-cmd --policy VPN-Killswitch --add-egress-zone VPN-Only
```

Now we only need to add our networks cards to the VPN-Only zone. This can be done through the NetworkManager GUI (or CLI) or through firewalld.

With NetworkManager open the properties window for the connection you want to filter and on the tab “General configuration” set “Firewall zone” to “VPN-Only”.

Or with firewalld:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone VPN-Only --add-interface=enp0s8
```

Test the setup and make it permanent:

```
firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```